# I get an error when I try to run t.test()

Tags: r, na, data-wrangling

I am trying to perform a t.test as follows:

```
t.test(data = a, score ~ group, paired = T)
```

However, I get this error:

> Error in complete.cases(x, y) : not all arguments have the same length

I think this is because group$target has some NAs.
How can I tell the t.test() function to run the test regardless (as the NAs are meant to be in there)?

Here is some info about my data:

```
table(a$group)
target: 96
nontarget: 96   

str(a$score)
num [1:192] 3 4.5 5.75 6.25 6 7 5 5.5 NA 5.25 ...

str(a$group)
Factor w/ 2 levels "nontarget","target": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

A sample of some of the data:

| ResponseId | group | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R_XZz2leQjPyBF4OZ | target | 4.750000 |
| R_yx5aiVCJfpz1Y9b | target | NA |
| R_z0RbO2yL1QT3jTX | target | 6.500000 |
| R_3DnI1SqwhDrourD | nontarget | 3.250000 |
| R_3e39IHkvt1yh0R8 | nontarget | 1.833333 |
| R_3e5kUZaUet2HYTw | nontarget | 2.916667 |

Comment: `t.test(data = na.omit(a), score ~ group, paired = T)`

Comment: @IRTFM the code you suggested gives the same error

Comment: Try setting the na.action option (on the ?t.test page).

Comment: Not sure if I'm reading your intro right, but you appear to be running a paired sample t-test on 2 different sets of data. A paired sample t test tests the difference between 2 observations on the SAME subjects. Else the differences between Obs 1 and Obs 2 on each subject simply cannot be formed. See any number of sources. Here's one from SAS https://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/sas/sas4-onesamplettest/SAS4-OneSampleTtest7.html and one from an R perspective http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/paired-samples-t-test-in-r

Comment: @Cristina. It's not because of the NA's. So you don't have paired data. Voting to close as typo-equivalent.

Comment: In addition to @John Garland's explanation, too many NAs would cause a specific (different) error message: "not enough 'x' observations"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Responding to the comments, I am concerned about @JohnGarland's question (are you **sure** you really have paired data?), but provided that you do (and the different `ResponseID` values are a red herring), I think that you have to discard all *pairs* with `NA` values (you say  "the NAs are meant to be in there", but since there is no way to include a pair with a missing value in a paired t-test [*see a counterargument below], you will have to discard them). One way to do this is to convert the data set to wide format, then use `na.omit()` (then use the slightly weird syntax required to do a paired t-test with wide-format data).

Read in sample data (short but it doesn't matter):

```r
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ResponseId  group   score
R_XZz2leQjPyBF4OZ   target  4.750000
R_yx5aiVCJfpz1Y9b   target  NA
R_z0RbO2yL1QT3jTX   target  6.500000
R_3DnI1SqwhDrourD   nontarget   3.250000
R_3e39IHkvt1yh0R8   nontarget   1.833333
R_3e5kUZaUet2HYTw   nontarget   2.916667
")
```

Convert to wide format:

```r
d_wide <- with(dd,
               data.frame(target = score[group == "target"],
                          nontarget = score[group == "nontarget"]))
```

This is a low-tech method. You can also use `reshape()` or `unstack()` from base R (although I have trouble figuring these out); `reshape2::reshape`; or `tidyr::pivot_wider`.

Once you've done this:

```r
t.test(Pair(target, nontarget) ~ 1, data = na.omit(d_wide))
```

The counter-argument is that you can actually do a little bit better with unbalanced data by fitting a linear mixed-effect model (LMM) with restricted maximum likelihood (REML); this can use the unpaired data to slightly improve the estimate of the mean values of the two groups; it should (??) give the same answer as the classical t-test when the groups are balanced.

```r
dd$pair <- factor(rep(1:3, 2))
mm <- nlme::lme(score ~ group, 
          random = ~1|pair, data = dd, method = "REML", 
     na.action = na.omit)
summary(mm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Partly working from context and partly working from how the data are set up. Most would not set up a paired sample t test in the way given in the OP with *2 factors* (target group vs. nontarget group are the same?, not usually, though sometimes does occur within participants). As well, note that

```
a <- data.frame(ResponseID = letters[1:6], 
     group = as.factor(c(rep("target",3),rep("nontarget",3))),
     score = c(4.75,NA,6.5,3.25,1.83,2.92))

t.test(data = a, score ~ group, paired = FALSE)
```

works just fine on the data structure as given.